# Adding new dependency to package.json in node causing error

Tags: json, node.js, npm, underscore.js

I am having serever.js file which contains the below code. I am having another package.json file which have dependencies. I later added underscore dependency to the existing dependency. It's throwing error on require("socket.io")(http) as require(...) is not a function. When I run the file using command node server error is coming after adding dependency.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "~3.4.0",
"jade": "*",
"socket.io": "0.8.x",
"logfmt": "~1.1.2",
"nodemailer": "~0.7.0",
"mongoose": "^4.2.4",
"body-parser": "~1.4.3",
"underscore": "~1.5.2" // when I add this line error is coming.
```

}

Can some one suggest me on this.

Comment: How exactly do you add the dependency? Do you use `npm install underscore --save`?

Comment: no i just ran npm install

Comment: Try reverting your package.json and run with --save option. Your package.json should be automatically updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket.io` with version `0.8.x` has a different syntax than the current one. See the documentation for 0.9: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/0.9

Currect usage:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
```